# saving state variable value to another for revert feature doesn't work

Tags: javascript, react-native, functional-programming

[image]

I am trying to update an array of `people` inside a Modal. If the user click s cancel button, it will setState people array back to its previous value when I click ‘Open Modal’.

So basically what I do is assign people array to another variable called cachedPeople `this.setState({ visible: true, cachedPeople: this.state.people  })` when Open Modal button is clicked.

"Change age of Ben” button has this onPress:

```
onPress={() => {
  const newPeople = [...this.state.people];
  newPeople[2].age = 20;
  this.setState({
     people: newPeople,
  });
}}
```

and on Cancel I set people array to cachedPeople

```
this.setState({ visible: false, people: this.state.cachedPeople });
```

but the value of `this.state.cachedPeople` also becomes the updated value of `this.state.people` before clicking Cancel button thus reverting doesn’t happen I don’t know where this is happening.

What I tried so far is saving it on `this.cachedPeople` instead of state but still happens.

heres a gist for the sample code: https://gist.github.com/damathryx/4a379d3c8919ee6431ee79b7a58426c9

Comment: what happens if you do it the way described above ? Does Ben still remain at 20 ??

Comment: @82Tuskers Thanks! updated the gif and details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to clone. people and cachedPeople are pointing to the same resources. So, I would

```
//not the best way to clone but ...
this.setState({ visible: true, cachedPeople: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.people))});
```

And,

```
onPress={() => {
  const newPeople = [...this.state.people];
  newPeople[2].age = 20;
  this.setState({
     people: newPeople,
    cachedPeople: this.state.cachedPeople
  });
}}
```

And,

```
this.setState({ visible: false, people: this.state.cachedPeople });
```

Please let me know if works for you.

Comment: However, I am not sure how we are able to edit `const` newPeople here.

Comment: Thanks! But since I use lodash I used _.cloneDeep instead.

Comment: Nice ! yes `_` library is a better solution indeed.

Comment: cloning *all* of the people when you only need to update one doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2):

**Clone responsibly**

You shouldn't be cloning the entire state; that doesn't make sense if you know you're only updating one object

```js
const state = 
  [ {age: 10}, {age: 11}, {age: 12}, {age: 13},  {age: 14} ]
  
const nextState =
  [
    ...state.slice (0,2),
    { ...state [2], age: 20 },
    ...state.slice (2)
  ]
  
console.log (state)
// [ {age: 10}, {age: 11}, {age: 12}, {age: 13},  {age: 14} ]

console.log (nextState)
// [ {age: 10}, {age: 11}, {age: 20}, {age: 13},  {age: 14} ]
```

What that might look like in your program (with variables `index` and `age`)

```
onPress={() =>
  this.setState ({
    people: [
      ...this.state.people.slice (0,index),
      { ...this.state.people [index], age },
      ...this.state.people.slice (index)
    }
  })}
```

---

**Be persistent**

Of course it's a pain to write functional programs without persistent data structures tho, which is why we have things like [Mori](https://github.com/swannodette/mori) or the more popular [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) – here's an example using Immutable. We use `toJS()` to convert back to primitive `Array` and `Object` types

```
const {List, Map} =
  require ('immutable')

const state = 
  [ {age: 10}, {age: 11}, {age: 12}, {age: 13}, {age: 14} ]

const nextState =
  List (state) .set (2,
    Map (state [2]) .set ('age', 20) .toJS ()) .toJS ()

console.log (state)
// [ { age: 10 }, { age: 11 }, { age: 12 }, { age: 13 }, { age: 14 } ]

console.log (nextState)
// [ { age: 10 }, { age: 11 }, { age: 20 }, { age: 13 }, { age: 14 } ]
```